# Mute all applications except one, and if open a new application keep it muted also

Tags: windows

I'd like to listen to White Noise while on the computer and turn the volume high. But if I do that, then if I open another new application the volume is extremely loud. If I use the Sound Mixer it only works for those applications and not all applications that may open in the future. How can I set Windows to only listen to 1 application and mute all others including all future applications that may open?

Comment: That is not possible to do. You can't set an application higher than the default volume (master control) and using Ear Trumpet it doesn't affect other applications. So I haven't found a way that is possible to do. Open a YouTube video in Chrome for instance like a White Noise video, set it to a very high volume, then try opening a new application and all new applications opened will be at max volume which will then be a painful experience. So based on this it just isn't possible to listen to White Noise at a high volume on Windows without getting shocked when opening new applications.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The question ciearly explains that that doesn't work well, because newly launched programs will have their volume set high

Comment: would finding white noise content that worked as you like at normal volume work? it seems like the real issue is the kluge of cranking the volume to generate the white noise.

Comment: I do that currently. I cannot turn it louder since there is no feature in Windows to isolate to only listen to 1 application, where any time a new application opens it will be muted also. If I do turn it louder then periodically if I open a new application it will blast it into my ears so that isn't something I want to do, because I reset all these settings right afterwards so it can be normal again. Would have to put a feature request in to be able to do this since it's not currently possible.